# MPI_Barrier - Only some processes passes the barrier

Tags: c, mpi, barrier

I'm facing a situation where only some processes bypass the `MPI_Barrier` function.

The problem appears in this fragment of code:

```
printf("[%d] Before barrier\n", mpi_rank);
fflush(stdout);
MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
printf("[%d] After barrier\n", mpi_rank);
fflush(stdout);
sleep(1);
```

After running it with 4 processes, I have the following output:

```
[3] Before barrier
[2] Before barrier
[0] Before barrier
[1] Before barrier
[1] After barrier
```

And the application freezes.

I was expecting that all processes were able to print the message `[id] After barrier`, but only process `1` printed it.

Why are not all processes passing the barrier?

I was expecting an output like:

```
[3] Before barrier
[2] Before barrier
[0] Before barrier
[1] Before barrier
[1] After barrier
[0] After barrier
[2] After barrier
[3] After barrier
```

I'm using openmpi with centos inside docker. The application starts several threads, but the fragment showed is not inside any of it.

Comment: Please explain why you think the problem has anything to do with the barrier. Seems to me that all four processes reached the barrier, and then process 1 was able to continue. What happens after that has nothing to do with the barrier.

Comment: Ok. Question edited, explaining the expected output. Thanks.

Comment: It's still impossible to say anything because you do not provide a minimal working example that reproduces the problem. There is nothing wrong with the code fragment itself. Thus, the first suspicion is that this behavior is due to some other part of the code (for example you might have called a non-blocking barrier on the other processes beforehand, which was matched by this MPI_Barrier call on process 1 now). Does it work with different number of processes? Maybe it's due to the environment, does it work on other systems? What do you mean by several threads?

Comment: @haraldkl, _"Unlike point-to-point operations, nonblocking collective operations do not match with blocking collective operations"_ - straight out of the MPI standard.

Comment: You definitely need to provide an [mcve].

Comment: @HristoIliev yeah, ok sorry, didn't check back. Well, then it shouldn't be that at least ;)

Comment: @HristoIliev Let's say I post a nonblocking barrier on a subset of the communicator ranks. Then I post a blocking barrier on this communicator. That would be a incorrect MPI program, right? Now undefined behavior might include what haraldkl suggested, or?

Comment: @Zulan, the order of collective calls (blocking or non-blocking) on a given communicator must be the same in all ranks, therefore such a scenario as the one you've described is indeed erroneous according to the standard. If the OP isn't really doing something messy, I would be more in favour of the hypothesis that this is yet another case of misconfigured network interfaces (Open MPI is very prone to those).

Answer (score -1):

I've been experiencing similar problems, began searching the web. I found - as far as I understand it - that the implementation of MPI_Barrier in OpenMPI might be buggy, depending on the specific version.

https://github.com/open-mpi/ompi/issues/3042

[MPI_Barrier doesn't function properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8230027/mpi-barrier-doesnt-function-properly)